# Batch renaming when the destination file need spaces

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zsh

I need to rename a batch of markdown files with random names based on the title name, and the destination name need to be with spaces (this is a spec). I'm trying this one-liner

```
for i in *;
do mv $i $(grep \# $i | head -1 | sed 's/# //' | sed 's/[_\?\!\]//' | sed 's/[:/]/ - /') ; 
done
```

but I receive the "the targer X is not a directory" error in the spaced name.

Any tips?

Comment: I'm not closing this as a dupe of "[Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766)" as that would prevent people from showing you more robust ways of doing what you are attempting. But the main issue is the non-quoting of variable expansions and command substitutions.

Comment: Can you give us a sample input filename? That pipeline can be simplified.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that the command substitution is not quoted, so it gets split into distinct arguments and each argument subject to pathname expansion (that latter part in `bash`, but not `zsh`), and when `mv` sees more than two, it assumes the last one is a directory to move the files to.

For the same reason, `$i` itself should be quoted (in `bash`), and to avoid problems if some file name starts with a dash `-`, you should use `./*` in place of `*` in the pattern, or put the end-of-options marker `--` in the `mv` command.

Also, I think we could simplify the way you process the filenames a bit. To start with, `sed` can take multiple commands, so you only need to call it once. You also probably want to add `/g` to the end of the `s///` commands, to make the substitutions for all matches, not just the first. Also note that 2 of those 3 backslashes in `[_\?\!\]` are redundant. Use `[_?!]` if you want to match on `_`, `?` or `!` or `[_\?!]` if you also want to include backslash (though `[_\\?!]` would make it more foolproof with some utilities).

```
for f in ./*; do
    mv -- "$f" "$(grep \# "$f" | head -1 | sed -e 's/# //g' -e 's/[_?!]//g' -e's/[:/]/ - /g')"
done
```

You could also combine the `grep` and `head` into the `sed` too:

```
for f in ./*; do
    mv -- "$f" "$(sed -ne '/^# / {s///; s/[_?!]//g; s/[:/]/ - /g; p; q;}' < "$f")"
done
```

Here, the commands inside `{}` are conditional on the pattern `/^# /`, and `q` at the end exits the script at the end of that block, so only the first matching line is processed.

Similarly in `awk`:

```
awk '/^# / { sub(/# /, ""); gsub(/[_?!]/, ""); gsub(/[:/]/, " - "); print; exit }' < "$f"
```

I might also change the last replacement to `s/[:/] */ - /`, so that a string like `blah: bleh` would turn into `blah - blah`, instead of `blah -  bleh` (with two spaces after the dash).

Answer (score 0):

Just add quotes around the target name:

```
 mv $i "$(grep \# $i | head -1 | sed 's/# //' | sed 's/[_\?\!\]//' | sed 's/[:/]/ - /')" ;
```

Comment: Combine the _three_ calls to `sed`? Or do it all with `awk`?

Comment: or `sed -e 's/# //' -e  's/[_\?\!\]//' -e  's/[_\?\!\]//'`